Bayesian Approach to Estimating Item Return Probability Given Time Since Sale
I'm attempting to estimate the probability of an item being returned given that X days have passed since the sale, using a Bayesian approach. I can calculate the overall probability of an item being returned using historical data. Additionally, I can determine the percentage of items returned within X days out of the total returned items by examining historical data as well. However, I'm unsure whether I should divide by 100%, as when I'm at day X, it's a certainty, or if I should use the total probability.
Here's how I'm currently approaching the problem:

Overall Return Probability Calculation: Using historical data, I
calculate the general probability of an item being returned,
regardless of the time since sale. Let's denote this probability as
P(Return).
Percentage of Returns within X Days: From the historical data, I determine the percentage of items that were returned within X days out of the total returned items. Let's denote this percentage as P(Return within X days | Return).
Adjustment for Time Since Sale: Now, I need to adjust the probability to account for the time since sale. I understand that I should divide by the probability of X days passing without the item being returned. Here's where my confusion arises: should I use 100% since, at day X, it's certain that the item hasn't been returned yet? Or should I use the total probability?

Here's a simplified version of the calculation I'm considering:
$P(\text{Return} | X \text{ days}) = \frac{P(\text{Return within X days | Return}) \times P(\text{Return})}{P(X \text{ days without return})}$
My question boils down to how to correctly determine
${P(X \text{ days without return})}$
Should I use 100% or the total probability?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Just a hunch, but what you're trying to model might be related to age-of-onset models.

Thanks Durden, I didnt know that branch of statistics. Anyway, I finally convinced myself that I should divide by the Total probability in this case, and seems to be working fine. Will look up about age of onset though, thanks for your help!
